# Parse PHP SDK, returns the same session token on every login

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-4, parse-platform

I try to logout user on the REST API and "become" the user at the logout process. But after I logout from parse when I login again I get the same Session Token with previous. Is it the way things happen or am I doing something wrong?

Here is my logout code snippet

```
public function postLogout(){
    $input = Input::all();

    $messages = [
        'required' => ':attribute cannot be empty',
        'invalidToken' => 'The token is invalid. User already logged out or never logged in.'
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($input, [
        'sessionToken' => 'required',
    ], $messages);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Response::json(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Request is not valid', 'error' => $validator->messages()->all()]);

    } else {
        try {
            $user = ParseUser::become($input['sessionToken']);
        } catch (ParseException $ex) {
            // The token could not be validated.
            return Response::json(['status' => 'error', 'message' => $messages['invalidToken'], 'error' => [$ex->getMessage()]]);
        }
        try {
            $user::logOut();
            return Response::json(['status' => 'success', 'message' => 'Logged out']);
        } catch (ParseException $ex) {
            return Response::json(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Logout error', 'error' => [$ex->getMessage()]]);
        }
    }

}
```

I am using laravel 4.2 with Parse PHP SDK. Thank you very much in advance.